# I've installed Tailwindcss in my project and configured the content after init.But,my styles are not getting applied in the page

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, tailwind-css, react-styleguidist, tailwind-elements

This is my tailwind config file.I've tried few other contents available in stackoverflow still Its not working.

anybody have any idea other than content any other mistakes?.Thanks in advance

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
content: ["./src/**/*.js"],
 theme: {
extend: {},
 },
   plugins: [],
    }
```

Comment: What is the framework/library you are using? ReactJS using CRA or NextJS?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the following in your index.css file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

In tailwind.config.js file

```
content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
],
```

For more details
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/framework-guides

Comment: Added that also.still not reflecting in UI

Comment: Hi @sathishKumar .Thanks for the effort to answer.  Its my bad. To anyone facing the same verify , where you're placing your tailwind config file. I've initialized my tailwindcss.config file outside the project folder.Just moved inside the folder mistakenly.its working fine.